# Single wire pacemakers

Tags: biomedical-engineering

There are single wire pacemakers used for regulating heart beat. The wire will conduct pulse to the heart. How can one wire be enough? Where is the reference wire for the stimulation of heart?

Comment: Hi, welcome to BIO.SE! What research have you already done on the topic? We ask that all questions here provide some evidence of previous research. Thanks